# Run-time error '429'

Tags: vb6, runtime-error, components, activex

I have developed an inventory management software using VB6. and i have copied it on Client's machine and it was working. but 3 days before they formatted the system and now i copied the software again an i tried to run the application. but i got the following error message

> Run-time error '429':
>   ActiveX component can't create object

Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most likely cause is a missing or unregistered/corrupt ActiveX control, see this [link](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/insprob.htm).  Does your application have an installation program you should have run?  Otherwise you'll have to look through the project dependencies and try and guess to see what is missing if the error context doesn't give any clue.

Comment: The Windows event log should tell exactly which DLL the program failed on.

Comment: @beaner, is that true? I've been using process explorer and fusion log viewer to track down the problem DLL unsuccessfully

Comment: I think it was more dependable in XP, or maybe I got lucky a lot. I have had a couple of instances lately where it didn't necessarily work. One was a dependent DLL called by my application, that in turn called another DLL. Still, the event log is always the first place I look, it can save a lot of time and effort. When I write an app, I document all the required DLLs to make someone's life easier.

Answer (score 0):

Does your app use any Office objects? I have a very dim and distant memory of writing some VB6 code back in 2001 or so that used Word and Excel COM objects, and that would spit a 429 if the app was installed on a users' PC who didn't have Office installed...