# Run-time error 429 VB6

Tags: vb6, runtime-error

I'm having a bit of an issue.  I'm trying to run this VB6 application that my company uses, but I get the below popup.  Now, I've installed VB6 run-time, I've re-registered the vbalTab6.ocx.  After some googling, I've even tried installing Microsoft Office and Access, and installing VB6 IDE.  All with no joy.  Any ideas?  Thanks for any and all help.

[image]

Comment: What else does your application use? It's missing one of those.

Comment: @Deanna I've registered/installed all third party software that is required by this application.  Looking through the code, I've made sure all the correct references and components are there and not missing.

Comment: Clearly not, you've missed something. You can either go through every reference and component to make sure it's installed or add debugging/logging to see what it's trying to load when it fails.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run-time error '429'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576089/run-time-error-429)

Comment: @Deanna:  I've followed the instructions on that other post, and found nothing.  I've used dependency walker, and it reported nothing missing.  Obviously something IS missing.  I just don't know what, or how to find it.

Comment: Try getting vbalTab6.ocx from a machine where this application does work (if you can) and copy it to the machine you are having the problem on.  Un-register it before you re-register it.  It could be you have the incorrect or corrupt version on your machine.  Just a thought.

Comment: @Fred I have just tried that, to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-register vbalIml6.ocx and ssubtmr6.dll. According to [their](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Code/Controls/Tab_Controls/vbAccelerator_ComCtl32_Tab_Control/VB6_TabStrip_Control_Full_Source.asp) website, they are dependencies. I'm inclined to believe this will fix the error.

Comment: You, sir, are a GD genius.  I was certain I'd scrubbed every bit of that site and every dll on my machine.  The SsubTmr6.dll is the one that did it.  Thanks again, very much!